# My Service doesn't seems to start.

Tags: android

I've got a service:

```
public class FileObserverService extends Service {

private FileObserverForNewFirFiles fObs;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i("FILE_OBSERVER_SERVICE: ", "INSIDE ONCREATE()"); 
    File f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/Bluetooth"); 
    createFileObserver(f);

}


public void createFileObserver(File f) {

    if(!f.isDirectory()) {
        Log.i("FILEOBSERVER: ", "FILE NOT A DIRECTORY!"); 
    }
    else {
        fObs = new FileObserverForNewFirFiles(f.getAbsolutePath()); 
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent i, int startid) {
    fObs.startWatching();
    Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "start monitoring file modification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


@Override 
public void onDestroy() {
    fObs.stopWatching();
    Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "stop monitoring file modification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
}
```

From my Main Activity, I call this class this way:

```
startService(new Intent(ThisClass.this, FileObserverService.class));
```

I thought that the `onCreate` method would print out something to the `LogCat`, referring to the first line of this method. But it doesnt seems to do it. Any hit?

Comment: Did you register the service in the manifest?

Comment: Yes, like this: <service android:name="FileObserverService" /> Do I need to specify the Package this service is located?

Comment: I don't know how you structured your app's package, but yes it should point to where the service is. Check logcat after you run the app to see if you don't get a warning about the service not found.

Comment: The Service is under the package "Logic", If i add <service android:name="Logic.FileObserverService" /> My console outputs Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Comment: Let's say your app's package(that is declared in the manifest) is "com.package". If you have the service in a sub package named `logic` you service would be declared `<service android:name=".logic.FileObserverService" />`. But before you do the modification check the logcat for warnings about the service not being found.

Comment: LogCat prints out:  Unable to start service Intent { cmp=my.package.com/Logic.FileObserverService }: not found.. I just edited my Package name, and it works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is an IntentService

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

just replace your method signature of onCreate

with onStartCommand

Basically you haven't done everything you need to do to get a regular old service going and IntentService will do all that work without any more effort from yourself.